# Lodash isUndefined providing unexpected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have a ternary in Node that uses Lodash isUndefined:
`sendUser.company = _.isUndefined(user.accounts[0].name) ? null : user.accounts[0].name;`
but when I try to run it I get
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: `user.accounts[0]` is undefined so js Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**_.get**](https://lodash.com/docs#get) to make it safe:

```
sendUser.company = _.get(user, 'accounts[0].name') || null;
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looking at the docs, seems that another way to write it would be: `sendUser.company = _.get(user, 'accounts[0].name', null)`

Comment: @KlatchBaldar Oh, you're right. I missed that. That's even more neat.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like accounts[0] may be undefined too - so you need to check for this too:

```
sendUser.company = ! user.accounts[0] || _.isUndefined(user.accounts[0].name) ? null : user.accounts[0].name;
```

Comment: Checking that `user.accounts[0]` is defined fixes the problem; is there any undefined check that would bubble up through the properties?

Comment: I don't think so @KlatchBaldar

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that user.accounts[0] is actually defined?

This looks like you are trying to check if 'name' is undefined. From what I understand of _isUndefined() it will only look for the specific value and thus cannot check for the state of the .name property as the user.accounts[0] is undefined itself.

You could always check for it also before checking the .name property.

Comment: Checking that `user.accounts[0]` is defined fixes the problem; is there any undefined check that would bubble up through the properties?